# iOS ERROR ITMS-90166 "Missing Code Signing Entitlements" when Uploading to App Store from Xcode Organizer with included framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to upload a new version of my app to iTunes Connect but since I added a today extension and the Armchair framework I am having an issue each time I try to upload my app to iTunes Connect.

The image shows that there is no entitlements for the Armchair bundle and framework. Maybe this is why I get that error :

[App Store upload issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0eGt.png)

It seems to come from the Armchair framework that is supposed to be included that way in my project :

[Project files explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5buo.png)

Intuitively, I would say this is a problem concerning AppID, bundleId or provisioning profile but I tried everything that came to my mind and everything I could read on the Web.

Does anyone have an idea about what I could try and what should be set for the Armchair project and targets ?

EDIT : I finally found that if I remove Armchair.bundle from Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases of my Target the upload works fine.
However, it seems to be needed for localization to work.

Comment: If you answered your own question, please post the answer for others and mark this question as answered.